# Выход из программы при завершении работы windows

Tags: delphi

Есть программа на Delphi XE. При старте программа сворачивается в трей (используется встроенный компонент TrayIcon). Как сделать чтобы при завершении работы Windows или при выходе из системы программа перехватывала эти события и выключалась? Если возможно нужны примеры кода.

P.S: привожу код сворачивания в трей при старте программы:

```
 DM.TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
 DM.TrayIcon1.Hint := 'Журнал заявок';
 // Убираем с панели задач
 ShowWindow(Handle, SW_HIDE); // Скрываем программу
 ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE); // Скрываем кнопку с TaskBar'а
 SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
   GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or (not WS_EX_APPWINDOW));
```

Comment: Если ваша программа нормально завершается, будучи не свернутой в трей (по нажатию кнопки закрытия, она же крестик) - она нормально выключится и при завершении работы Windows. Никаких дополнительных манипуляций не требуется.

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но на Windows XP такие манипуляции не работают.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернуто. Какие "такие" манипуляции? Что значит - "не работают"? В программе возникает исключение? Она зависает? Прерывается, как будто ей сделали TerminateProcess? Говорит "не хочу завершаться"?

Comment: При выключении компьютера или выходе из системы, программа в трее препятствует этому. До тех пор пока не закрыть программу вручную, компьютер не выключается.

Comment: WM_QUERYENDSESSION вызывает событие OnCloseQuery. Попробуйте его.

Comment: У Вас случайно нет никаких сообщений или вопросов перед выходом из программы? Может они блокируют нормальное завершение?

Comment: Что происходит, если в окне программы нажать на "крестик" (системная кнопка закрытия окна)?

Comment: Есть вопрос при выходе из программы. При нажатии на крестик происходит сворачивание формы в трей.

Answer (score 2):

В главную форму добавляете метод и переменную:

```
...
private
  FSessionEnding: Boolean;
  procedure WMQueryEndSession(var Message: TMessage); message WM_QUERYENDSESSION;
```

В реализации пишете:

```
procedure TForm1.WMQueryEndSession(var Message: TMessage);
{ чтобы программа не препятствовала выключению компа }
begin
  FSessionEnding := True;
  Message.Result := 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := FSessionEnding; { закрываемся, если выбрали выход из меню или выключаем комп }
  if not CanClose then
    cltrycn1.HideMainForm;    { иначе сворачиваемся в трей } // cltrycn1 - аналог TrayIcon
end;
```

Если есть другие способы выхода из программы, например, кнопка выход в меню, то, чтобы программа могла закрыться, перед выходом нужно установить `FSessionEnding` в `True`. Например:

```
procedure TForm1.Exit1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSessionEnding := True;
  Close;
end;
```

---

**UPD:** Если в форме не используется обработчик `OnCloseQuery`, то в этом случае переменная `FSessionEnding` не нужна, а обработчик сообщения `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` нужно использовать, например, такой:

```
procedure TForm1.WMQueryEndSession(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result := 1;
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: Данный способ, к сожалению, не помог. Приходится все равно принудительно закрывать программу, чтобы выйти из системы или перезагрузить компьютер.

Comment: В каком методе расположен ваш код по сворачиванию в трей?

Comment: На главной форме в следующем методе:

Comment: procedure TForm6.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);

Comment: Что такое `DM` в вашем коде в вопросе?

Comment: DM - DataModule (Модуль данных)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Исправил код на предложенный Вами и все равно все так же нужно принудительно закрывать программу самому.

Comment: Посмотрите в отладчике вызывается ли обработчик `WMQueryEndSession`, а лучше сделайте минимальный пример для воспроизведения ситуации и выложите его где-нибудь.